# Using ArangoDB for time series data?

Tags: time-series, arangodb

Can ArangoDB be used as a time series store? In other words, can I use just ArangoDB and not also have to leverage something like InfluxDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as we point out at the example of [logstash](https://www.arangodb.com/2015/02/using-arangodb-logstash-output/) it is possible.
However, unlike RRDB or other timeseries storages, Arangodb can't do a compaction on its own.
You should have a look at [howto handle time stamps in ArangoDB](https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/DateFunctions.html).